# Custom validation attribute does not work when editing a record

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validationattribute

I have an entity called Doctor, in the create doctor form I added custom validation logic as follows:

```
public class UniqueDoctorNameAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        string name = value.ToString();
        HospitalEntities db = new HospitalEntities();
        int count = db.Doctors.Where(d => d.DoctorName == name).ToList().Count;
        if (count != 0)
            return new ValidationResult("A doctor already exists with that name");
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

and then in the Doctor model class:

```
public class Doctor
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [UniqueDoctorName]
    public string DoctorName { get; set; }
}
```

and it works as expected when creating doctors but it also shows up in the edit form of Doctor, I know one way to remedy this is to use a viewmodel in the create form and do the validation there but that would require alot of debugging on my part as I've written alot of code depending on it being passed a Doctor model, so how do I fix that ?

Comment: What do you want exactly ? You need the error message to appear only on the form level or just close the related field?

Comment: in controller action edit one you can exclude this validation for DoctorName

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad When I exclude the validation using ModelState.Remove("DoctorName") it doesn't show up in the form but still shows up when saving changes saying "Validation failed for one or more entities" and when examining EntityValidationErrors it says "A doctor already exists with that name"

Comment: @CodeNotFound I want to exclude this exact validation when editing doctors only and still have it when creating them

Comment: Then the only and clean solution is to use view moidel :D

Comment: i think you have DB level contraint as well on the column, in that case that would be difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your custom validation attribute to accept your Id property so that you can use that when you do your check against your db.

```
public class UniqueDoctorNameAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string _IdPropertyName;

    public UniqueDoctorNameAttribute(string IdPropertyName)
    {
        _IdPropertyName = IdPropertyName;
    }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value,
                                                      ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        string name = value.ToString();
        var property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_IdPropertyName);
        if (property != null)
        {
            var idValue = property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
            var db = new HospitalEntities();
            var exists = db.Doctors.Any(d => d.DoctorName == name && d.Id!=idValue);
            if (exists )
                   return new ValidationResult("A doctor already exists with that name");

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

When user creates a new record, the value of DoctorId will be 0 and when editing it will be a valid doctorId value.

Now in your view model,

```
public class Doctor
{
    public int DoctorId { set; get; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [UniqueDoctorName(nameof(DoctorId))]
    public string DoctorName { get; set; }
}
```

`nameof` will return a string "DoctorId"(*name of that property*). If your c# version does not support this keyword, simply use the string "DoctorId" as the constructor parameter.

Comment: Yes. You need to pass the doctorId in the hidden field. See the where clause i used `d.Id!=idValue` . That means, When you are editing Scott's record which has Doctor ID, 5 and you are changing it to Sam(Already existing record with Id 7) the Any method will return true. But if you are changing to Harvest (Assume we don't have such a record) It will return false.

Comment: Ahhh, so it won't throw an error if it has the same id and same name, that makes sense yeah, I will try this solution and give feedback.